# Silence error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, automatic-ref-counting, clang

I have recently converted my project to use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting).

It doesn't really do a very good job of knowing when to actually release an object, and often because I have lots of allocations being performed, my application has excessively high memory usage because the existing objects aren't being deallocated when they're closed from view.

All I need to be able to do is disable ARC for that file, and everything should be OK. I did that, added the release statement, and it worked perfectly. Except of an error.

Whenever the project isn't being built (ie. the error disappears and the build succeeds while building it) it shows an error stating that ARC prohibits the sending of the release message to an object, even though I explicitly added an exception for that file in the Project Settings.

All I really need to do is silence the error, as there is no error (as it builds successfully).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it an error, or a warning? Having the exact text of the warning/error will assist in helping people know what you might need to set.

Comment: Is the file included in another target, like a unit test target? You need to add the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag to that file in each target that includes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after several builds and cleans, the error has miraculously disappeared.

These problems have been frequent in Xcode 4, I got an unused variable warning from something that was clearly being used.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be an issue with Xcode 4.2 at least, possible 4.2.1 also. But, back to the ARC thing, you say it doesn't "do a very good job of knowing". If your memory usage is high and increasing under ARC, it's because you are keeping references you shouldn't be keeping. Turning off ARC may be a short term band-aid, but at some point you should consider fixing those underlying bugs in your code. You'll eventually run into them again, ARC or no-objc-arc.